# Spring Boot 2 web application not starting in Tomcat 9

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have an application that is currently built on Spring Boot 1.5.9 and I am trying to update it to the latest Spring Boot 2 version.

The application uses spring-security, spring-security-taglibs, spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, spring-session-jdbc, jstl (jsp pages) and connects to two databases, I also use profiles to configure the application differently in development and production environments.

I was successfully able to upgrade my development application. I only needed to modify my `pom.xml` and a few java files.

During development I usually use the integrated Tomcat server. i.e. The one you get when you run  `mvn spring-boot:run`

As a sanity test I also installed Tomcat 9.0.43 (this is the same build that is used in my production environment). The Spring Boot 2 version of the application works perfectly fine using this method.

However, all my problems started when I tried to deploy my application into the production environment.

When restarting the Tomcat server, I don't see any indication that it even detects the Spring Boot 2 application. In Spring Boot 1, I would usually get the Spring logo and a bunch of startup messages. Visiting the website in a browser shows `The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists`

The Spring Boot application does not generate any log files and Tomcat's log files merely indicate the application was deployed successfully.

What could be causing this issue.

- Both my development system and the production server have JRE and JDK 8 installed (although, different minor versions)
- Both systems are running the same version of Tomcat.
- Both systems run on Windows. The server runs on Windows server 2013 and the development environment is on Windows 10.
- I use Visual Studio Code for development and debugging

### Update 1

The spring boot 2 version of my application is using version 2.5.1
Here are a few things that I have done:

- I have made sure that the application extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`
- I can't put my local Tomcat installation in the production server (at least, not without a lot of issues), but I've copied the server's Tomcat installation onto my development machine and verified that the application DOES start correctly.
- The only property in my POM is `<java.version>8</java.version>`
- While both environment have JRE and JDK 8, they may have different minor versions

### Update 2

I created a brand new Spring Boot 2.5.9 application (using Spring Initializr and no dependencies) and tried to run this in a Tomcat 8.5.20 instance on the server. I also created an `index.html` to display a simple `Hello World!!!` if the application starts correctly

- The application works fine on my development system (using both integrated Tomcat and separate Tomcat installation)
- In production, the Spring Boot application did not start (i.e. I got a 404)
- It did not appear to generate any logs or errors.

Comment: `the production server have JRE 8`, I would always go with a JDK.

Comment: I have edited the post to clarify that both environments have JRE and JDK 8 installed.

Comment: Sounds weird, but probably, you overlook something that we cannot see. I would prepare on the develop environment a standalone tomcat folder and deploy the app. If starts ok, then copy the whole tomcat folder (with deployed app) to server and start on server again.

Comment: Well, it does not appear to be a dependency. I have updated the question with more troubleshooting steps that I have tried...

Comment: I would try to build a jar with what you have done in Update2 <packaging>jar</packaging>. Then run the spring-boot jar with `java -jar app.jar` on both environments. Still no output ?

Comment: Sorry for the long silence! Switching to jar packaging actually worked. But, in the end, I managed to get it working by upgrading my production environment to Java 17, Tomcat 9.0.62 and Spring Boot 2.5.12. I am having issues with Spring Boot 2.6 but that's a different problem.

Comment: @KarthikSankaran Could you tell me how you solved your problem, I'm facing the same problem. tomcat 9.0.63, spring-boot 2.6.6 java 17